# jQuery-function to toggle class exists twice, but only works once

Tags: php, jquery, css, toggle

I have one index.php page, whose content changes whether you activated a session or are logged out.

When users are logged in, a click on the link "showhide" should show the class "users".
When users are logged out the link "showhide" is hidden and instead the link "showhide2" is visible, which should show the class "users2" when its pressed.

I found a jQuery-snippet online that does exactly this and works fine for the link "showhide"
Unfortunately it doesn't work for the link "showhide2" - the class is always visible...

Here's my code:

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top:10px;height:100%;">
      <?php
      /*echo "Der Nutzername ist ".$_SESSION['user'];
      echo "<br>Die Session lautet ".$_SESSION['sessionname'];
      echo "<br>".session_id();*/


      $sArray = explode(".",$_SESSION['sessionname']);
        $session1 = $sArray[0];
        $session2 = $sArray[1];
      $sessionausblenden = $_SESSION['sessionname'];
      if (!isset($sessionausblenden)){
          echo "<style type='text/css'>
        #showhide{ 
            visibility:hidden !important;
        }

        .users{
        visibility:hidden !important;
        }

        #logout {
        visibility:hidden !important;
        }
        </style>";


      }
      elseif (isset($sessionausblenden)){
          echo "<style type='text/css'>
        #showhide2{ 
            visibility:hidden !important;
        }

        .users2{
        visibility:hidden !important;
        }
        </style>";

      }


      ?>
    <a id="showhide" href="#" style="background:#<?php echo $session2?>;">+</a>
    <a id="showhide2" href="#" style="background:#<?php echo $session2?>;">?</a>
    <a id="logout" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="logout.php">-</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.users').hide();

            $('a#showhide').click(function () {
                $('.users').toggle(400);
            });
        });
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.users2').hide();

            $('a#showhide2').click(function () {
                $('.users2').toggle(400);
            });
        });
    </script>

   <center><h1>Group Chat In PHP</h1></center>
   <div class="chat">

    <div class="users" style="background-color:#<?php echo $session2?>;">
     <?php include("users.php");?>
    </div>
        <div class="users2" style="background-color:#<?php echo $session2?>;">
     <?php include("users.php");?>
    </div>
    <div class="chatbox">
     <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      include("chatbox.php");
     }else{
      $display_case=true;
      include("login.php");
     }
     ?>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

You can see the live-version here: http://team3.digital-cultures.net/index.php
Just enter a name of your choice and choose an option from "Start" and "Ziel" and your session is started (and a chat is opened).

Can you help me finding the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're trying to hide content from logged out users simply by using css, make sure it's content you don't mind them seeing if they are logged out and they work hard enough to try and see it. it's easy to unhide hidden content using an inspector if you know how.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter when they manage to see the content - the classes are basically empty unless they are logged in (content gets then pulled from a database).

Comment: When I login there is no showhide link?

Comment: It's the coloured button in the top-left corner with a plus-sign... Clicking it toggles a list of other users in the same room and the start/destination you chose

Comment: Yes, found it. It doesn't have an event bound to it. Should be simple to resolve. One moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an event is not being bound to #showhide2. If you listen at the document level and let it bubble to #showhide as the target, it may work. This can happen for dynamically loaded elements.

Change

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.users2').hide();

            $('a#showhide2').click(function () {
                $('.users2').toggle(400);
            });
        });
```

To

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.users2').hide();

            $(document).on('click','#showhide2',function () {
                $('.users2').toggle(400);
            });
        });
```

Most importantly, please resolve this error:

`$(".msgs").animate({scrollTop:$(".msgs")[0].scrollHeight});` on line 2 of chat.js `$(".msgs")[0]` is undefined.

There are no elements matching `$('.msgs')`. Wrap it with the following:

```
if($('.msgs').length) {
    $(".msgs").animate({scrollTop:$(".msgs")[0].scrollHeight});
}
```

This maybe why the event isn't getting bound.

Comment: @weheri you've got an error in your code. open a console and check the log! I've highlighted the error at the end of my answer.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Unfortunately "scrollHeight" is needed - it automatically scrolls down to the newest message. I removed it now and even when new messages appear it stays at the top.
But how can it print an error when it obviously does work in action?

Comment: @weheri I don't understand what do you mean by "how can it print an error?" btw, be a good citizen and tick the answer if it works for you. if you think i've been extra helpful, you might even want to give my answer an upvote.

Comment: Okay, figured it out.
It always tried to find "scrollHeight", even when the user wasn't logged in (and therefore the chatbox didn't even exist yet)
Solution: The script is now only loaded, when the user logs in

Comment: @weheri You can use the `if` check I added to the question to make sure the element exists too.